# eBay Kleinanzeigen API access (eBay Classifieds Germany)

Tags: ebay-api

For a mobile app we would love to integrate the eBay Kleinanzeigen (www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de) API. Goal is to (API `GET`) get all the classifieds in a certain (German) zip code.
However the documentation is not very useful. 
The API under `https://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/api/ads` request login and password for this API. We used the `username` and `password` from www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de and the eBay Partner (Developer) login credentials but both are not working.

Does anyone know how to use it and what credentials we need to use it or has experience with this API?

Comment: You can find the documentation here: https://api.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/docs/pages/home and a client here: https://github.com/tejado/ebk-client

Answer (score 20):

The eBay Kleinanzeigen API is not public available and is used internally for some applications, including their own apps.
Still, some third parties have access to it, but this is always based on business reasons and contractually regulated. There is no regular developer program to access the API.
If you think you have a product which would work great with eBay Kleinanzeigens inventory, and for that also want to have access to the API you should contact their business development team.

Comment: Do you have some actual sources or references concerning this?

Comment: If someone will ask me what "self-signed" means, I'll reference this answer and this comment ;)

Comment: Is the info about the api kleinanzeigen.de still up to date?

Answer (score 1):

> The eBay Kleinanzeigen API is not public available and is used internally for some applications, including their own apps.

If this is the case and you don't need to provide the "eBay Partner" credentials in the apps, they seems to be part of the code. 
An overview of the apps can be found here:
https://www.ebayclassifiedsgroup.com/mobile.html

This is not a guidance to do it, just a syllogism.

Comment: the link you posted is dead